# how change volume in unity video player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a video player project and I want to add a slider for volume
I could not be able to find volume control for video player but audioSource component has
for now I did not find the need to use audiosource the audio comes with the video player 
can I change volume with video player or do I have to link it with an audiosource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using `SetDirectAudioVolume`? See:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.SetDirectAudioVolume.html for reference:

```
 SetDirectAudioVolume(ushort trackIndex, float volume)
```